# Time shown in incorrect language

Tags: views

I have a php_view field in a view, it basically pulls a date field on a specific node, and then use the php function setISODate to get the 'monday' date of the week.

The thing is, i'm on a french language site and the date that the function return is in english, not that I don't like english hehe but the month just doesn't fit very well in the display on that view

Here's the code.

```
// Retrieve the date field of that node.
$node = node_load($data->nid);
$date_field = $node->field_date;
$date = $date_field['und'][0]['value'];

// Put the year in $annee and the week number in $semaine.
$annee = date("Y", strtotime($date));
$semaine= date("W", strtotime($date));

// Get the monday date of that week
$lundi = new DateTime();
$lundi->setISODate($annee , $semaine);
print "Semaine du " . $lundi->format('j F Y');;
```

?>

I've tried to use the following code, but it doesn't do anything.

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra'); 
print (strftime("%j %F %Y", $lundi));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'French_France.utf-8', 'fr.UTF8', 'fr_FR.UTF-8', 'fr.UTF-8');
//setlocale(LC_ALL, '') ;// if you try on local windows server

$annee = date("Y", strtotime($date));
$semaine= date("W", strtotime($date));

// Get the monday date of that week
$lundi = new DateTime();
$lundi->setISODate($annee , $semaine);

print "Semaine du " . strftime("%A %d %B %Y",strtotime($lundi->format('j F Y')));
```